# How to replace the image behind a servingURL?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to replace a image behind a servingURL in Googles AppEngine? My thought is, that I have a profile-avatar and when the user change its avatar, I simply replace the image but preserve the servingURL. In this case, I do not have to change the URLs stored at my microservice.

How can I do it? - can't find anything ...

Comment: did you replace binary content under same BlobKey? or created a new blob?

Comment: I used Google-CS for that. I just uploaded a Image with the same name to replace the old one.
In my upload servlet i use 
String servingUrl = imageService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(file).secureUrl(true));
to get the serving url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload an image to Cloud Storage to the same bucket with the same object name, the new image will be served instead of an old one. Note, however, that images are cached. You can disable caching for your images, but that will degrade the performance of your app - especially in the case of frequently requested images such as avatars.

Updating a record in a datastore maybe a good solution after all, especially since users do not change their avatars very often.

Comment: I assume cashing is disabled by setting the chache-control flag to no-cache? is there another way to disable caching e.g. gsutil?

Comment: Yes, you can change ACLs on your objects using gsutil.